# How to retrieve multiple values from SQL to label

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, ado.net

I want to retrieve multiple values from my SQL database to several labels on a single aspx page. What is happening now, is that I am successfully retrieving the values from the first row but then when it comes to the second row and afterwards, it keeps repeating the values from the first row.

This is the code that I am using to select the values from the database. Can anyone help me solve this to retrieve other rows aswell?

Code behind page:

```
public partial class filmes : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ENTDB"].ConnectionString;
    string str;
    SqlCommand com;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        con.Open();
        str = "select * from FilmesSeries order by IDFilmesSeries desc";
        com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

        int ID=1;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           ID++;
           Label tituloControl= (Label) Page.FindControl("Titulo"+ID);
           if(tituloControl!=null) 
           {
              tituloControl.ID=" Titulo"+ID;           
              tituloControl.Text= reader["Titulo"].ToString();
           } 

           Label GeneroControl= (Label) Page.FindControl("Genero"+ID);
           if(GeneroControl!=null) 
           {
              GeneroControl.ID=" Genero"+ID;           
              GeneroControl.Text= reader["NomeGenero"].ToString();
           }
        }

        reader.Close();
        con.Close();

    }
}
```

filmes.aspx page:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <asp:Label id="Titulo1" runat="server" />
            <asp:Label id="Genero1" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <asp:Label id="Titulo2" runat="server" />
            <asp:Label id="Genero2" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you want print each row on separate line(or on separate labels) right??

Comment: @JaydipJ Yes. Currently Titulo1 and Genero1 are doing it right, but Titulo2 and Genero2 are repeating the same value but I want to get the values from the second row and so on.

Comment: Do you have Titulo1,Titulo2,Titulo3.........labels is right?

Comment: Are you controls statically defined on the page, with IDs like `TituloX` and `NomeGeneroX`?

Comment: @Andrei Yes, I am using labels with the IDs that are shown above.

Comment: @JaydipJ Yes, that's right.

Comment: Why to uses textboxes like this?? define a grid control. put this text controls inside the grid. from SQL end take all values directly in form on datatable. Assign it to grid source. you can out paging to avoid performance as well as other data structures controls, too!

Comment: Below given approach will help you

Comment: @wickenex Do you want to show all the rows values? I mean dynamically generate labels for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the right index of controls to assign to:

```
int i = 1;
while (reader.Read())
{
    ...
    i++;
}
```

Then you need to retrive these controls from the page:

```
int i = 1;
while (reader.Read())
{
    Label titleLabel = (Label)this.FindControl("Titulo" + i);
    Label genreLabel = (Label)this.FindControl("NomeGenero" + i);
    ...
    i++;
}
```

And finally assign

```
int i = 1;
while (reader.Read())
{
    Label titleLabel = (Label)this.FindControl("Titulo" + i);
    Label genreLabel = (Label)this.FindControl("NomeGenero" + i);
    titleLabel.Text = reader["Titulo"].ToString();
    genreLabel.Text = reader["NomeGenero"].ToString();
    i++;
}
```

Be aware though that if you have say 10 items in database and only 9 pairs of labels on the page (that is `Titulo9` is the last one, there is no `Titulo10`), code above will fail, so make sure to do some error handling.

There are ways to optimize over that:

1. Put all your labels into an array (make sure to maintain right order), and then you can do `titleLabels[i]`
2. Have a repeater or a gridview, which represents a list of your entities, and defines template with necessary labels. Then you could bind data to them from your database, which would result in a much prettier and easier to maintain solution, and less error prone. However that is really a separate subject, not too fit to this question, look up tutorials online for that.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your solution. I have a Gridview on a different page which already shows all the values from the database but it might be harder to pass those values from one page to the other, that's why I have tried this method.

Comment: @wickenex, the approach I am talking about does not assume any data passing from the other page. You should not be passing data base stuff from page to page anyway. This is a very, very common workflow: go to database, load data, bind grid view with it. If you have multiple pages with similar functional, this needs to be done for each of them separately, that much is true

Comment: Your code is giving me this error "nullreferenceexception was unhandled by user code" once it reaches "titleLabel.Text = reader["Titulo"].ToString();"

Comment: @wickenex that error is because the label the code is trying to assign the text to was not created by you. You simply need to add the code if(titleLabel !=null) before it reaches to titleLabel.Text

Comment: @Andrei and GH Karim I want to thank both of you for your suggestions.  I ended up using a repeater like Andrei suggested and it's working perfectly for my needs :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all the values for each row and assign them in labels. You could create those labels dynamically for each row and assign them to the page:

```
int ID=1;
while (reader.Read())
{
   ID++;
   Label TituloLabel= new Label();
   TituloLabel.ID=" Titulo"+ID;
   TituloLabel.Text= reader["Titulo"].ToString();

   Label GeneroLabel= new Label();
   GeneroLabel.ID=" Genero"+ID;
   GeneroLabel.Text= reader["NomeGenero"].ToString();

   Page.Controls.Add(TituloLabel);
   Page.Controls.Add(GeneroLabel);
}
```

**[Edit]** To bind the controls to a certain control on the page. You can get that control by id. As an example, assuming you have a div for example:

`<div id="placeHolder" runat="server"></div>`

The following code binds the created labels to it simply by finding that `div`:

```
Page.FindControl("placeHolder").Controls.Add(TituloLabel);
Page.FindControl("placeHolder").Controls.Add(GeneroLabel);
```

**[Update]**  This code will help to generate labels for each row however if you want to map out previously created ones, then **Andrei's** approach should work!

**[Edit] [2]** To map out to hard-coded labels:

```
int ID = 0;
while (reader.Read())
{
   ID++;
   Label tituloControl= (Label) Page.FindControl("Titulo"+ID);
   if(tituloControl!=null) 
   {         
      tituloControl.Text= reader["Titulo"].ToString();
   } 

   Label GeneroControl= (Label) Page.FindControl("Genero"+ID);
   if(GeneroControl!=null) 
   {       
      GeneroControl.Text= reader["NomeGenero"].ToString();
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried your code and it does exactly what I want. The only thing that would have liked is to insert the values in the places where I have added my labels.

Comment: @wickenex That's fine then you can use the .FindControl function and find the control on the page and bind it to it

Comment: @wickenex I updated my answer to demo how to achieve what you want :)

Comment: I didn't write that exactly how I wanted in the end but is it possible for somehow insert the values in the labels that I have created instead of a global div like you said?

Comment: Do you mean that you have hard-coded labels you have already created in the page?

Comment: Then in this case Andrei's approach will work for you.

Comment: @wickenex I have updated my answer to map out to hard coded labels.

Comment: The code has just a tiny error, 'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' could be found.
The thing is, I already am using: System.Web.UI;
 System.Web.UI.WebControls;  System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
, System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts; and despite all that, the error still remains if I had the type that the program is requires.

Comment: I did now yes. Tell me, did you wanted your code like "Page.FindControl("Titulo"+ID) or the way it is written above? If it is your way, that gives me an error because you are also including "as Label" as a string. If not, well nothing is being shown in the page.

Comment: @wickenex See code above and make sure you include these lib (using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;). It should be fine now!

Comment: It's not working at all my friend, nothing that was supposedly generated is shown anymore and I have both of these controls. I added both the page and behind the page code to my OP to better show you where I might be making a mistake.

Comment: @wickenex I do apologies it was my mistake for not testing the code. I updated it again. It should be fine now!

Comment: No worries. I am starting to understand the code but it's still not working although I already know why it's not showing anything. TituloControl and GeneroControl are not really getting anything, they are showing as null.

Comment: @wickenex this is an odd behavior. I've just tried it with your labels from your original post  and it works perfectly!.

Comment: That is odd. Do you happen to have by any chance a jsfiddle of it or a screenshot of your program? You are also running it a ASP.NET Web Application using C# as main language correct?

Comment: @wickenex correct! I even tried it against a real database and it still works. I have attached an image screenshot of the code.

Comment: I appreciate your effort buddy, I'm really out of words. I made sure that my code was exactly the same as yours, heck I even created a new project with that same code and nothing :(

Comment: I'm sorry your problem wasn't solved. I would suggest that you use your new project to help in debugging the issue in isolation. The only solution I can suggest you do for debugging is: 1- make sure your reader retrieves data. 2- try to put Page.Controls.Count to see if controls were registered properly. 3-Use hard-coded label ids and try to find them using the code above and see if you can retrieve any. good luck!